# problem using CABasicAnimation to animate multiple CALayers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I've been having lots of problems with animations in my board game iPhone app. i use the following function to animate the computer player moving the counter:

```
-(void)animateCounterMoveFor:(int)playerType counterId:(int)countId {

    // set up the move to an end point
    CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [move setDuration:3.5];
    [move setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((xPos), (yPos))]];
    [move setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [move setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    CAMediaTimingFunction *tf = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [move setTimingFunction:tf];

    // enable the animation stop to set layer to right position
    [move setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countId] forKey:@"counterId"];
    [move setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:playerType] forKey:@"playerType"];
    [move setDelegate:self];

    // add move to the layer
    [layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"moveAnimation"];

}
```

.. and then a delegate sets the layer position and removes the animation when its finished (otherwise the counter moves back to its start position).

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CABasicAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {

    NSNumber *counterId = [anim valueForKey:@"counterImageId"];
    NSNumber *playerId = [anim valueForKey:@"playerType"];

    int countId = [counterId intValue];
    int playId = [playerId intValue];

// code here gets position information using counter and player id

    // set the final position of the layer when the anim stops, then remove the anim
    [layer setPosition:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];
    [layer removeAnimationForKey:@"moveAnimation"];

}
```

This all works fine when one counter is moving, but when one counter takes another i use the same method to move both. I thought that a copy of the animation was passed to the layer and so i could call it to move the first counter layer, and then call it again straight after for it to move the second one. I log out the object ids and two different move anims are created, but only the second counter moves. animationDidStop: is called twice and the correct counter information is passed each time.

Any ideas about how to make it work? I've trawled through quite a lot of CAAnimation/CALayer questions so i guess its not just me having trouble with it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you know the final position ahead of time?

I would just set the position of the object within the animateCounterMoveFor: method, otherwise it'll snap back to the original position, since the calayer doesn't actually move until you set it.

```
-(void)animateCounterMoveFor:(int)playerType counterId:(int)countId {

    // set up the move to an end point
    CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [move setDuration:3.5];
    [move setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((xPos), (yPos))]];
    [move setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [move setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    CAMediaTimingFunction *tf = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [move setTimingFunction:tf];


    [layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"position"];   // Replaces the previous position animation on the layer
    [layer setPosition:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];        // Sets the final position after animation is finished

    // enable the animation stop to set layer to right position
    [move setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countId] forKey:@"counterId"];
    [move setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:playerType] forKey:@"playerType"];
    [move setDelegate:self];

}
```

Comment: when i tried setting the position in the animateCounterMoveFor: method  the counter snapped straight to the end position and then ran the animation from the end pos to the end pos (i think) so no movement happened. that's why i was mucking about with the animationDidStop:

Comment: after doing quite a lot of checking of my code while i posted this question, i afterwards went back to it with a better perspective and checked all my assumptions - i was passing in the player and counter id the wrong way round ... duh .. so actually this code does work. there may well be better ways of doing it though!

Comment: You may have needed to set the fromValue.

Comment: setting the fromValue did also fix it without using animationDidStop